# Linux high-speed(/no impact) storage (for settings) and PHP

Tags: php, linux, settings, non-volatile

I'm sorry if the title sounds confusing, if you get any better ideas after this description, feel free to suggest.

In short, I'm using PHP on Linux with the following hypothetical files/code:

**job.php:**

```
if(setting_get('started')!='on'){
  setting_set('started','on');
  echo 'Starting...';
  set_time_limit(0); // ad infinitum (in theory)
  ignore_user_abort(true); // ignore disconnection
  while(setting_get('started')=='on'){
    // do something
    sleep(10);
  }
}else echo 'Already started!';
```

**interface.php:**

```
switch($_REQUEST['action']){
  case 'status':
    echo 'Service is: '.setting_get('on');
    break;
  case 'start':
    header('Location: job.php');
    break;
  case 'stop':
    setting_set('started','off');
    break;
  case 'restart':
    setting_set('started','off');
    header('Location: job.php');
    break;
}
echo '<a href="?action=status">Check Status</a>';
echo '<a href="?action=start">Start</a>';
echo '<a href="?action=stop">Stop</a>';
echo '<a href="?action=restart">Restart</a>';
```

The code should be quite self-explanatory. Basically, `job.php` should be able to run only a single instance, indefinitely until the user specifically stops it from `interface.php`, which is there to mediate between the user and the job.

My problem is `setting_get` and `setting_set` - they're just hypothetical functions which can be easily replaced with a flatfile or a database.
The thing is that they're called *a lot* which is why they should run fast as well consume little memory (if possible, even none at all).

Ideas?

**Edit:**  It should be noted that the settings I'm saving so far could as well be a simple boolean flag.

**Edit2**  With regards to Memcached / APC / Redis. I was wondering, couldn't I use the normal mysql functions over a DB of type MEMORY? I wonder how much overhead there is?
Thing is, I'd rather use something I've already got than having to install new stuff, but then again, it depends on implementation.

Comment: a couple of quick notes on the code - you'll need 'break;' statements between the switch case's, and in the job.php loop, a sleep, to avoid a tight loop driving your CPU to 100% usage.  I've also tended to do the same thing (remote control of a job-runner) via a queue (Amazon SQS or Beanstalkd)

Comment: Alister - Right, my bad. Typing off the top of my head :). Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

How about [APC](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)'s [apc_store](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) and [apc_fetch](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php)?

Comment: or memcached will also perform the same role. APC isn't so happy with files started on the command line however.

Comment: redis would be another data cacheing option, an alternative to either apc or memcache

Comment: in memory DB engine is a pretty good idea, try it out and see what the performance is lke

Answer (score 0):

> set_time_limit(0); // ad infinitum (in theory)

you can run your job in `cron` without such limit.

Use shared memory (fastest), memcached, redis (given in order of speed).

Comment: Actually I can't use cron. I'm using inotify, and loop timing is quite tight. WRT memcached / redis, I'll look for my best option.